# McAfee doesn't like Stack Overflow Podcast #94 - We Don't Care If Bret Is Famous

Tags: bug, status-declined

When I click on the link to

Stack Overflow Podcast #94 - We Don't Care If Bret Is Famous

McAfee says

---

"Whoa!

Are you sure you want to go there?

http://stackoverflow.blog/2016/11/Stack-Overflow-P... may be risky to visit.

**Why are you seeing this?**

When we visited this site, we found it exhibited one or more risky behaviors."

---

is it just me or is there something wrong with the link?

McAffee says this about that

URL entered (http://stackoverflow.blog/2016/11/Stack-Overflow-Podcast-94-We-Dont-Care-If-Bret-Is-Famous/?cb=1 ) is not a valid website URL or has no data

Comment: Here is a link to [McAfee Site Advisor](https://www.siteadvisor.com/sites/http%3A//stackoverflow.blog/2016/11/Stack-Overflow-Podcast-94-We-Dont-Care-If-Bret-Is-Famous/%3Fcb%3D1) showing this message

Comment: I just visited http://stackoverflow.blog/2016/11/Stack-Overflow-Podcast-94-We-Dont-Care-If-Bret-Is-Famous/ and got no problems.  (I'm using avast!)

Comment: @Winther, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Great. And McAfee doesn't see anything wrong.

Comment: I vote to reopen. It is reasonable close to being about "the software that powers the Stack Exchange network." It's not [math.se] specific, but this does not make it off-topic on this per-site meta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not a bug on our side.

I've submitted the URL for review here:

[image: Request URL review]

If this bothers you, I suggest you do the same.